# Where can I find owner's manuals for Troy Bilt Horse rototillers?

Tags: gardening

I have a Troy Bilt Horse rototiller that I am guessing is perhaps a second generation tiller from the 1980s.  The serial number located on the upper right of the transmission has been painted over at least once, but maybe more, so I don't yet know the serial number.  Does anyone know where I can find manuals for these early generation rototillers?  I need to purchase some parts for it, which seem to be very available.

Answer (score 3):

I found the Horse manuals on the MTD website. There are PDF manuals for multiple generations of the tillers here.

**If you do not know the serial number**, like me, you can use this link:  http://manuals.mtdproducts.com/mtd/Public.do?model_num=horse&serial_num=1&doSearch=Y

**If you know the serial number**, you can instead use this link:
http://manuals.mtdproducts.com/mtd/Public.do?model_num=horse
[image]